# Scroll down animate or trigger block

Tags: css, ajax, scroll, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

I'm trying to recreate something similar to the following:
https://www.apple.com/uk/ipad-mini/design/

When you scroll down on the page it seems to understand that a certain area, when viewed, triggers an animated element. I'm trying to base next steps on this but unsure what to start in. I understand elements of HTML, CSS, DIV Tags and potentially switching on a hidden block when viewed might be the answer. But need advice of the simple trigger element. Java? PHP? CSS?

So when the user scrolls down maybe 30% a hidden element appears or animates. I would animate in adobe edge if that helps.

Any good?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with Jquery (scrolltop)

```
$(window).scroll( function(){    
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
   // If window is scrolled by 150px do this
}
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great ill have a go! Simply not a coder but understand the principle of your code.